# Hot reload does not work after making a new App with saving the file with Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I am a beginner with Flutter, and I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.45.1 on a Mac, I've seen some people reporting this issue and downgrading, but it looks like downgrading is not the solution and I do not want to downgrade, eventually we will have to use the latest version at some point.

I realized the following:

Every time I create a new App, I change anything like the text displayed or title from the "Example App" flutter creates for us and just by saving the App, I can see the results instantly on the emulator.

But, when I delete everything and start creating any sample, the hot reload by saving the App does not work, I have to rely on pressing the "Restart" button every time I want to see the changes on the device emulator.

When I save the App, I can see at the bottom "Syncing files to the device iPhone 11 Pro Max".

So, why it does not work like the dummy App when I change anything, and save?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, post your "flutter doctor -v"

Answer (score 0):

The course I was following, the instructor explained later why every time we have to restart the application and why the hot reload did not work, because I did not have the Method build inside the Stateless Widget Class, which he created later to wrap all the code we have created so far.

Now it's working, every time I make a change and save, the App changes.

Below the code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```